# Where can I find options for "rails new" command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried typing "rails new -h" into the command line but got nothing.

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

just use this command

```
rails new --help
```

Comment: That does not give me any options for new

Comment: It does for me, with Rails 3.1.0. I usually use `rails new --help` instead, but both seem to work. What *do* you get doing that?

Comment: Oh, thanks for the question.  I was getting: "Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.
Type 'rails' for help."  but I now realize this is because I was in the app directory.  If I go up a directory, I get the options.

Comment: `--help` doesn't show any options for encoding.  `rails new` on Windows creates files with ANSI encoding, when it should use UTF-8.

Comment: Here is a gist for those who found this searching for the options and don't want to open a terminal. https://gist.github.com/brianpetro/2c59916af11c65aac155

Comment: Does anyone know where the source code for this executable can be found?

Answer (score 16):

Rails 5

```
$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.0
$ rails
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
  -M, [--skip-action-mailer], [--no-skip-action-mailer]  # Skip Action Mailer files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -P, [--skip-puma], [--no-skip-puma]                    # Skip Puma related files
  -C, [--skip-action-cable], [--no-skip-action-cable]    # Skip Action Cable files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
      [--skip-listen], [--no-skip-listen]                # Don't generate configuration that depends on the listen gem
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]        # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test], [--no-skip-test]                    # Skip test files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file
      [--api], [--no-api]                                # Preconfigure smaller stack for API only apps

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
```

Rails 4

```
$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.6    
$ rails
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]        # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test-unit], [--no-skip-test-unit]          # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file
```